# How to improve this match pattern?

Tags: sql-server, patindex

This pattern works as expected. I want to improve it by:

- Merging the repeating patterns : [0-9][0-9][0-9] into one. I tried
  [0-9{3}], no success.
- Specify the special character - instead of [^0-9A-Z]

```
SELECT PATINDEX('[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9A-Z][0-1][0-2][^0-9A-Z][0-3][0-9]', '2014-10-28');
```

Comment: I looks like you are trying to find valid dates.   Why not try_convert(date,YourCol) is not null

Comment: If you want to stick with the patindex, you can trim it a bit   SELECT PATINDEX('[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-2]-[0-3][0-9]', '2014-10-28');

Comment: I need to stick with PATINDEX since I will be expanding this pattern to include time with milliseconds.@JohnCappelletti

Comment: In that case, rather than     [^0-9A-Z] you can list the possible characters as such 
    [-./]  but it really won't buy you much (if anything)

Comment: To include time just use try_convert with the datetime datatype. That seems a lot easier. Then if at all possible fix the table so you stop storing dates as strings.